# Pyspark Size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

i want to write a dataframe partitionned :

```
df.repartition(50).write.mode('overwrite').format("com.databricks.spark.avro").save(data_path)
```

I chose 50 partitions because the data are light, when everything works well there are 1.7MB per .avro file, so i don't understand why sometimes it fails with this error 'Pyspark Size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE'

The files have never reached more than 3mb.

The Exception :

````py
more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE at
sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:869) at 
org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore$$anonfun$getBytes$4.apply(DiskStore.scala:125) at 
org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore$$anonfun$getBytes$4.apply(DiskStore.scala:124) at 
org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1337) at 
org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore.getBytes(DiskStore.scala:126) at 
org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getLocalValues(BlockManager.scala:520) at 
org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:764) at 
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:334) at 
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:285) at
org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38) at 
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323) at 
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287) at 
org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38) at 
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323) at 
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287) at 
org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38) at
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323) at 
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287) at 
org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38) at 
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323) at 
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287) at 
org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38) at 
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323) at 
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287) at 
org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38) at 
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323) at 
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287) at 
org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38) at 
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323) at 
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287) at 
org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)at
org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53) at
org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108) at 
org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338) at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:6
17) ... 1 more End of LogType:stdout action.xml aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.6.jar
 aws-java-sdk-kms-1.10.6.jar aws-java-sdk-s3-1.10.6.jar azure-data-lake-
store-sdk-2.1.4.jar azure-keyvault-core-0.8.0.jar azure-storage-5.4.0.jar 
commons-lang3-3.4.jar commons-lang3-3.4.jar.backup container_tokens distcp
 guava-11.0.2.jar hadoop-aws-2.7.3.2.6.4.194-2.jar hadoop-azure-
2.7.3.2.6.4.194-2.jar hadoop-azure-datalake-2.7.3.2.6.4.194-2.jar hcatalog 
hive hive2 job.xml joda-time-2.9.6.jar json-simple-1.1.jar 
launch_container.sh lib_20220227155043 logger.sh mapreduce-streaming mr-
framework okhttp-2.4.0.jar okio-1.4.0.jar oozie oozie-hadoop-utils-hadoop-2-
4.2.0.2.6.4.194-2.jar oozie-sharelib-oozie-4.2.0.2.6.4.194-2.jar pig 
propagation-conf.xml sharelib.properties spark sqoop tmp ```
````

Comment: Can you share the exact error log you are getting?

Comment: the code is added to the original post, thanks